# html css * {...} : can't change the font-size

Tags: html, css, class

Seems like I'm stucked.
Why does the code below display a message of 12px, but not 50px? Isn't class1 have the highe
How to fix it if **I'm not allowed to change the * properties**? Even !important does not help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            *
            {
                font-size : 12px
            }

            .class1
            {
                font-size : 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="class1">
            <span>why it is not 50px font size?</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't be able to change the star selector; it's bad code, and clearly causing problems. What's the reason you can't change it?

Comment: I'm working on an EXTENSION of a project (fork). I'd better do not touch that css files that was written by another person.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because * also selects the `<span>` tag inside your `<div>`.

So * is more specific in this case and thus has priority.

```
.class1 span
{
    font-size : 50px;
}
```

The above would work.

Comment: Or use body {} instead of * {}

Answer (score 2):

Or You can use !important

```
.class1 {font-size : 50px !important;}
```

A working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gWQeZ/

Comment: Using `!important` should always be considered a last resort. If you need it, then it usually means that either you don't understand CSS priorities, or there's something elsewhere in your CSS that needs fixing.

Comment: Or if you are using a third party scripts which auto generate css and you need to override it, or if you need a fast fix or if the person who is asking this question has no enough understanding of CSS. the purpose here is to provide different solutions and then he can choose whatever suits him. and i do i agree with your comment that !important should be the last resort

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
div.class1 span 
{
    font-size : 50px;
}
```

`*` will select the span inside of div. either removing of `<span>` as child element will work. or target the  explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. I know that. Is there any better idea? I mean once I include that bad.css file that contains * , it breaks a lot of staff so I have to rewrite a lot of span inside many divs. Is there any better solution like to "cancel" that *{font-size:12px;}?

Comment: you can overwrite the value, but there is no way to unset it. i see no problem overwriting the value, you can even use multiple selector separated by comma (,). to target different tags.

Comment: You could do `.class1 * { font-size: inherit; }` but I suspect that might cause issues too.

Answer (score 1):

`*` would include the `<span>`, So you can either give span an id or a class and apply the css rule to that. or do it like :

```
.class1 span {font-size:50px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector `*` is a catchall (meaning it selects *everything*.)

So for your `span` to be selected, you need a more specific selector:

```
.class1 span
```

should work but you can also select it to be even more specific:

```
div.class1 span
```

Or you can add a class to the span itself and select it with that

```
span.class2
```

:)